# Yii 2 check if function exist in yii\base\Model

Tags: php, arrays, loops, yii2

I am trying to solve problem of cheeking function in standart gii
I need to check if function exist in yii\base\Model 
and if it exist, add prefix to this function
For example if you generate model with yii2\gii
you will have somthing like this

```
 /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getErrors()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Error::className(), ['groupId' => 'id']);
    }
```

I need to change function name when it generate to

```
/**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function funky_key_getErrors()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Error::className(), ['groupId' => 'id']);
    }
```

I extend basics gii and rewrite function but it doesn't help
My code from generators\model\Generator, i think i need to check $relations in this function

```
        protected function generateRelations()
            {
\before basik yii code\
            $relations = self::checkExistClass($relations);
            return $relations;
            }

   private static function checkExistClass($relations)
    {
        foreach ($relations as $name => $relation) {
            foreach ($relation as $functionName => $functionValue) {
                $functionNameGet = 'get' . $functionName;
                $directory = new Model;
                if (method_exists($directory, $functionNameGet)) {
                    $relation['funky_key_' . $functionName] = $functionValue;
                    unset($relation[$functionName]);
                }
            }
        }
        return $relations;
    }
```

Comment: Why exactly you want to change this kind of internal functions of yii. They have written their code in a very well mannered organized way may be your change will hamper other functionalities.

Comment: @Neeraj Kumar, they do not check if function already exists, and i have an error because when i generate function it have same function, so for that i need to add prefix or something to it